# SetInterval() with “if” condition that give the value to a array

Tags: javascript

I have an setInterval in which there is a condition that defines the array `ta`.
The array is defined for the first time the condition is met, but when the condition is not met, I want to keep the same amount of the first array as given,
but for the second time, when the condition is not met, the `ta` array is not defined. How can I solve this problem?

```js
var a=1;
setInterval(() => {
if (a==1){
  var ta=[];  
  for(let i=1;i<3;i++){
    ta.push(i);
  };
  console.log(ta);
  console.log("ta");
  a=2;
} 

console.log(ta); // why this is undefined in Second round onwards ?

},5000);
```

Comment: why do you take a global `a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your array `ta`  outside of the `setInterval()`, otherwise it won't be accessible

```js
let a = 1
const ta = []

setInterval(() => {
  if (a === 1) {
    for (let i = 1; i < 3; i++)
      ta.push(i)

    console.log(`ta while equal to 1: ${ta}`)
    a = 2
  }
  console.log(`ta for every 5s interval: ${ta}`)
}, 5000);
```